# Is there any way to transform a shape without new bounding box created every move?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've searched everywhere, but cannot find a way. All I want to do is take a rectangle shape and match it to another perspective layer by moving each corner to the matching corner of the perspective shape. Seems like the transform tool creates a new bounding box everytime I move a corner, making it impossible to ultimately achieve this. See example image below for what I'm trying to do: [image: here].

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use perspective tool for match the all four corner of both rectangles
[Perspective tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCYZr.gif)

adjust the image as your requirement.

i have attached Gif image for detailed process.

I hope you can understand easily.

Reagrds,

Comment: Thanks so much for the visual description!